# Is there something I am missing in registering the Helpers in app.js file?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, helper, express-handlebars

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
var expressHbs =  require('express-handlebars');

    var hbsss = expressHbs.create({
    
      helpers: {
        sum: function (num) {
          return (num+90);
        }
        }
    });
    
    app.engine('handlebars', hbsss.engine);
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

I am trying to call sum function in one of the .hbs page as below:

```
<td>sum = {{sum 10}}</td>
```

But I am getting error Handlebars Missing helper!!
P.S. All my handlebar pages i hve used the extension as `.hbs` not `.handlebars`.
And so I am using hbs here not handlebars in `app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

Is that make a difference?

Also is t necessary to include the below lines of code in create{()} method?

```
  defaultLayout: 'status',
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
```

When to use these lines?
Let me know what changes I need to do or add or look upon to solve this error?`

Comment: I took a quick look at the [Express guide on template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and the [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) documentation and I wasn't able to tell why you're seeing the error or whether `hbs` vs `handlebars` matters. The easiest way to figure it out would be to just try it :) Ie. change `app.set('view engine', 'hbs')` to `app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')`, and change your file extensions from `.hbs` to `.handlebars`.

Comment: In general it's good to stick to how things are done in the documentation, and the [express-handlebars documentation](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) uses `handlebars` for the `view engine` and for the file extensions. Deviating from that without having a good understanding of it could lead to unintended issues down the road even if you don't experience them right now. Although in the long run I'd recommend trying to develop that deep understanding of how it works.

Comment: Also, make sure that `app` is in scope. Ie. you have `app = express()` above `app.engine` or are `import`ing `app` such that if you `console.log(app)` before the `app.engine` and `app.set` lines, it gives you what you're expecting.

Comment: @Adam thanks for your input! I tried and changed all the file's extensions as handlebars from hbs. And noow I am getting this error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Sulekha Yadav\Desktop\grumpytext\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Comment: Can you explain me what is the use of this and there should be main.handlebars files there in mainLayout folders?   defaultLayout: 'status',
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views'),

Comment: Also do i need to call the helpers inside main.handlebars as it's saying its missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221678/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-biku7).